# string or binary data would be truncated - do I need to specify size?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am inserting data into a SQL Server database using VB.NET.

The column I am inserting into has a datatype of `VARCHAR(MAX)`

My SQL parameter is:

```
objPrm = New SqlParameter("@arg_strMessageText", SqlDbType.VarChar)
```

When I run the program I get an exception

> String or binary data would be truncated

The size of the data I am trying to insert is 7,941 characters.

I thought the `VARCHAR(MAX)` datatype handled 8000 characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well VarChar(MAX) can hold upto 2GB data. but you use Varchar(Max) you have to use `-1` something like..

```
 objPrm = New SqlParameter("@arg_strMessageText", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1)
```

Comment: Tried that, still get the same exception. I check the parameter size and it is set to -1 which might be the cause? As my data is a positive length?

Comment: Never mind, an audit table which gets populated via a trigger has an inconsistent schema.